# Authorize access to write and delete only if the user knows the node - Rules Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I face an issue : I want the user of my web program to write and delete data in firebase only if he knows where it is and I don't understand what rules have to apply to that.
For instance, my user has an id which is '785475' and I want to only give him access to '/data/785475'. How do I do that please?
Do I have to use authentification?

Thanks in advance and please have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Firebase security rules permission cascades. So in your model and requirement, it is important that the user doesn't have read access to `/data`, as that means they could read `/data` **and** all nodes under it.

To the trick is to only grant them access to the individual child nodes of `/data`:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "data": {
      "$any": {
        ".write": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With the above nodes, a user can delete any existing node that the know the key of, but they can't read (or query) the entire `/data` node to determine those keys.

---

To only allow them to overwrite existing data, and not create any new nodes, you can do:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "data": {
      "$any": {
        ".write": "data.exists()"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For more on this, and other examples, check out the Firebase documentation on [new vs existing data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#existing_data_vs_new_data).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helps me, now my user can't write anywhere exept in "data" but I would like to allow them only a modification of the nodes for instance right now they can write new nodes in data, what I want to do is allowing them only to modify existing nodes without the ability to add ones. Something like that :
`{
  "rules": {
    "data": {
      "$any": {
        ".write": true IF &any EXISTS,
         "$any": {
          ".write":true,
      }
    }
  }
}`
I tried "update" but it does not seem to work. Thanks again :!

Comment: Thanks, I built my rules thanks to your help! Please have a nice day!